# Maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException When testing Junit tests

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, junit

I'm running a batch little python script that auto grades a bunch of java programs by running all of their Junit tests. I take the exported eclipse projects, unzip them, then call maven to run the tests. I haven't changed anything from the original eclipse projects, and the tests run fine in eclipse.

This is my first real time using Maven.

For reference, I'm running on Windows 10, and my paths are all set correctly, and they match what's happening in Eclipse, I believe.

```
Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-

10T11:41:47-05:00)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.9
Java version: 1.8.0_111, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

**I've gotten the following error:**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
org.apache.maven.surefire.util.SurefireReflectionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/brandeis/cs12b/PA7/PA7/target/test-classes/edu/brandeis/cs12b/PA7/KnowledgeBaseTest (wrong name: edu/brandeis/cs12b/PA7/KnowledgeBaseTest)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.loadClass(DefaultScanResult.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.DefaultScanResult.applyFilter(DefaultScanResult.java:95)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.scanClassPath(JUnit4Provider.java:194)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:92)
    ... 9 more

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

**Here's a copy of the POM file:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>edu.brandeis.cs12b.pa7</groupId>
    <artifactId>PA7</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>PA7</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   edu/brandeis/cs12b/PA7/PA7/target/test-classes/edu/brandeis/cs12b/PA7/KnowledgeBaseTest
>   (wrong name: edu/brandeis/cs12b/PA7/KnowledgeBaseTest)

It is weird : you seem to have twice `PA7` package in the project but no in the package of the class.
Is it maybe your problem as Maven refers `wrong name` as error.

Besides, you should avoid using uppercase in package :  `edu/brandeis/cs12b/PA7`. It is contrary to Java conventions.